# Wait inbetween functions in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yield-return

I want to wait 2 seconds between the `Start()` and the `Update()` function, my code:

```
void Start () {
        r = GetComponent<RobotController>();
        r.postEffectroPos(new Vector3(0.2f, 0.0f, 0.3f), 0.1f);
        StartCoroutine(wait2Sec());
    }
```

My wait function:

```
IEnumerator wait2Sec() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
        Debug.Log("Robot is moving to start position");
    }
```

In Update():

```
if (controlRobot)
        {
            moveRobot();
            movePlayerToRobot();
        }
```

I want to move my robot at the start to a set position and then enable the movement of the robot. The problem is that `moveRobot()` gets the current position of the robot and posts a call with an adjusted position depending on the input.

So the robot does not wait in the `Update()` function for the `Start()` function to finish the 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The `Update` function is called independently of the `Start` method. The only way of postponing an `Update` method that I can think of is to block the UI Thread, which you should **never do**.

One way of achieving what you want is to set a flag on the `MonoBehaviour` that gets set to `true` from inside start and in the `Update` method check for the flag. Something like this:

```
class Robot:MonoBehaviour
{
  bool shouldMove = false;

  void Start () {
    r = GetComponent<RobotController>();
    r.postEffectroPos(new Vector3(0.2f, 0.0f, 0.3f), 0.1f);
    StartCoroutine(wait2Sec());
  }

  IEnumerator wait2Sec() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    Debug.Log("Robot is moving to start position");
    shouldMove = true;
  }

  void Update()
  {
    if (controlRobot && shouldMove)
    {
        moveRobot();
        movePlayerToRobot();
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I didn't use `controlRobot` for this because I didn't knew what was it purpose, but if this is used for the same reason, just set `controlRobot` from `wait2Sec`.